# Git Webhooks workflow

Tags: git, webhooks

Dear stackoverflow community, I need some advice about bitbucket webhooks.

I decided to go with the following workflow.
I work on local -> pushing to dev branch bitbucket -> bitbucket makes post request to mydomain:7000 where my node server is listening -> node server runs gulp-git to pull code from dev branch to a /www folder in order to test the code on my server at dev.mydomain

Although I'm restricting access to :7000 to bitbucket IP's only, someone could spoof the IP address and leave me vulnerable to ddos and multiple code pulls from bitbucket, because bitbucket uses a POST request for my webhook listener

How can I do this safely? I know I can make a corn job on server to pull code, or i can run a ssh script from my laptop to pull code on server. But I want to automate this because I'm very lazy. Is there a safe way ?

Answer (score 0):

I use github webhook very often, you can do:

1. Keep the webhook url `Secret`
2. Set the Secret field in `setting/webhook`.
3. Hash the url with secret key.

Maybe you need this [git webhook platform](https://github.com/NetEaseGame/git-webhook), with Flask + celery + react. Can manage Multiple servers.